# Chrome extension to highlight searched keywords in a website

Tags: chrome, search-engine, search, text-search

I have to make use of search engines, like Google, Yahoo, etc, to retrieve information from many websites.

But when viewing these re-directed websites, it would be tedious to always manually press Ctrl+F to locate the searched keywords.

Is there a Chrome app which could automatically highlight these searched keywords in a website?

Comment: As you say web*site*, the highlighting should work for all pages on that site, not only for the page you visited from the search results?

Comment: The single page visited from the search results would do fine.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to enter a search term, say to Google, click on that link form a Google search result to open a page, and have the original search term highlighted on that page?

Answer (score 1):

[Highlight Keywords for Google Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/highlight-keywords-for-go/nhahncknpppipmgjchbbhehkfglelepf?hl=en) does this, but only for Google.

Screenshot from their page:

[image]

It automatically highlights any of the words you searched for when you visit the page. It can be toggled off by clicking the icon in the menu bar.

Comment: Just to clarify - it does not highlight words searched for by `CTRL+F`?

Comment: No, it doesn't :(

Comment: Then maybe a comment, rather than an answer? It's a good tip, though

Comment: @Mawg yeah, you're probably right for the question, but the OP said in the comments it would be OK if it was from the search page... so I think I might as well leave it here

Answer (score 1):

This extension does this: [find+ | Regex Find-in-Page Tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/find%2B-regex-find-in-page/fddffkdncgkkdjobemgbpojjeffmmofb?hl=en-US) by B. Richardson.

There is also a [Github repo](https://github.com/brandon1024/find). "A find-in-page extension for Google Chrome with support for regular expressions."

By default it does not use Regular Expressions, but it highlights all occurences like "Find in Page" does. In the settings dialog there is a slider control that lets you choose how many items max to highlight. Default is "infinity".

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Highlight Search Keywords](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/highlight-search-keywords/nflhamjkngakbdnihackfkjoabknmooi) extension for Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this: Web-Highlights (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-highlights-web-text-h/hldjnlbobkdkghfidgoecgmklcemanhm) chrome extension. It looks really similar to the marker on https://Medium.com and you can access your marks from anywhere.